# pass array of strings to a function which takes const char**

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function which takes an array of const char** as a parameter

```
void Foo(const char** bar);
```

I can pass an array of const char * to it

```
const char *bar[2];
bar[0] = "test";
bar[1] = "me";

Foo(bar); // works fine
```

I want to do the same when 'bar' is std::string array instead of const char *

```
std::string bar[2];
bar[0] = "test";
bar[1] = "me";

Foo(bar); // cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string [1]' to 'const char **'
```

I know the way convert std::string to const char *. Is there any way I can do it in the above case

Comment: Did you mean to write `const char *bar[2] = {"test", "me"};`? `const char *bar[0] = "test";` doesn't do what you think it does. An array of `std::string`is fundamentally different from `const char *bar[2];` BTW.. The compiler is right that such won't be convertible.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: Depends a lot on what Foo expects. The function signature alone doesn't tell anything about the contract. If you just want a const char** from a string &(bar.data()) would be that

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly but here

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Foo(const char** bar, int num) {
    while(num > 0) {
      std::cout << bar[--num] << std::endl << std::flush;
    }
}

const char** toCharArray(std::string* arr, int num) {
    // If we ever alloc with new with have to delete
    const char** buffer = new const char*[num];

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        buffer[i] = arr[i].c_str();
    }

    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    std::string bar[2];
    bar[0] = "test";
    bar[1] = "me";

    // Capture the result 
    const char** charBar = toCharArray(bar, 2);
    Foo(charBar, 2);

    // So we can free it later
    delete[] charBar;
}
```

Arrays in memory do not have a `length` or `size` member like other languages so we pass in the size via function arguments. Second since we want to pass in an array of strings and get an array of chars out of it, we'll need to construct another array dynamically. Only way to do this is to use new. This stores the chars on the heap instead of the stack so when the function `toCharArray` finishes, the data will live on. So we store the result in `charBar` so that we can `delete[]` the array later.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot do it directly

```
auto arr = std::vector<const char*>();
auto s1 = std::string("test");
auto s2 = std::string("me");
arr.push_back(s1.c_str());
arr.push_back(s2.c_str());

Foo(arr.data());
```